# Ruby console input halting at 1024 characters

Tags: ruby, console

I have a script that takes console input into a variable and requires pasting in a string longer than 1024 characters.

When I try to paste more than 1024 characters it stops accepting input after 1024 and just shows a truncated string.  Manually typing characters also hits this limit. How can I get around this?

iTerm doesn't seem to be the problem, I can paste more than 1024 to bash no problem.

```
irb
2.1.3 :001 > a = STDIN.gets
```

I have the same symptom when I use the  Highline::import gem and the `ask` method.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what that points to. Ruby version? Terminal? Machine?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.0 on ubuntu. I tried `puts "a"*2000; p gets.size` and copypaste the output as input. No surprises.

Comment: I reproduce it on Ruby 2.2.0 installed via ruby-build, Mac OSX 10.10.2, iTerm2. Bash and IRB work fine with a long copy/paste. But a ruby script that uses "gets" truncates and freezes when I copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gem install rb-readline
```

In your script:

```
require 'rb-readline'
```

and then, to read a line:

```
a = Readline::readline
```

Does that solve it?

If so, you may also want to look at compiling your Ruby with readline:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X